IAM user + inline s3 allow putObject policy vs IAM Identity Center user + permission set + inline s3 allow putObject policy, why the 2nd doesn't work?
I have spent quite some time trying to understand why AWS SDK (in my case it's JavaScript) using keys of my AWS IAM Identity Center user having a permission set with an inline S3 full access policy (moreover, I did try attaching a managed AmazonS3FullAccess one which is a complete duplicate of the one below)
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

cannot put anything to my bucket.
Then I tried creating a IAM user with a customer inline policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MySid",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*"
        }
    ]
}

and AWS SDK can put files to my bucket just fine using the keys of this 2nd user.
CORS is configured correctly (with a * placeholder for Principal) for the bucket which is confirmed by the fact the 2nd config works fine.
Why is that? What is the difference between IAM Identity Center users with permission sets including inline policies and IAM users with inline policies?
Is it because IAM Identity Center users choose a permission set on logging in and AWS SDK doesn't apply any permission set for them unless in some way told to?

There is no difference - have you checked if there are any permission boundary, bucket policy etc which could cause the issue? What's the exact error?

As it is my, let's say, blank VPC I am sure there's no permission boundary nor bucket policy which could cause the issue.
And I checked manually as well just to be sure.
I suspect the permission set is not applied for the user created via IAM Identity Center until I tell somehow SDK to do that. As I added above my guess is that it may be similar to how a permission set is chosen when logging into Amazon Web Console using a IAM Identity Center user. There's clear manual choice of a permission set (in my case out of 1 permission set available).
